# jQuery: Window resize function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of of code which is really working fine:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".fadeinbg").click(function(){
      $("#content").fadeIn();
   });

   var height = $(window).height();
   var width = $(window).width();
   $('#content').css({"min-height": height + "px"});

   $('#content').css({"width": (width - 200) + "px"});
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve now is to update the jQuery after a browser window resize by adding this line at the bottom of my code: `$(window).resize()`

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".fadeinbg").click(function(){
      $("#content").fadeIn();
   });

   var height = $(window).height();
   var width = $(window).width();
   $('#content').css({"min-height": height + "px"});

   $('#content').css({"width": (width - 200) + "px"});

   $(window).resize(function() {
   });
});
```

... but somehow this doesn't work at all. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How does this not work? Does the rest of your working code stop working? Does the code inside the [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) callback function not fire? You haven't posted any code inside said callback function, so... nothing would happen on `resize` the way you're showing it to us.

Comment: Put the code in a function, call the function.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code is still working, but the window width and height doesn't update after resizing the browser.

Comment: @epascarello: Ok, thanks. And how do I do it? I'm really new to all this...Would be really great, if anyone could provide some working code.

Comment: can you able to post, what has to happen after resizing the window, that will be helpful to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overthinking it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".fadeinbg").click(function(){
       $("#content").fadeIn();
   });

   var setSize = function () {  //define a function with the code you want to call    
       var height = $(window).height();
       var width = $(window).width();
       $('#content').css(
           { 
               "min-height": height + "px", 
               "width": (width - 200) + "px" 
           }
       );
   };

   $(window).resize(setSize);  //set the function to resize
   setSize();  //call the function now
});
```

Comment: @Tbyas Note that the `$(window).resize()` call is simply setting up the `setSize` function to execute whenever a `resize` event is detected on the `window` (the browser window). This doesn't immediately call the function. The `setSize()` call afterwards (which is entirely unrelated to the `.resize()` call) will execute the function, so that the size is set on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is very much working try resize you window and check the console. It is working fine. Test rest of your project

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log("width------:"+$( window ).width() +" height------:"+$(window).height())
    });
});
```